# Oracle table name change

Tags: oracle, ddl, dml

If i have to rename a table which has got synonyms, partitions, read permissions to other users etc.

what would be the best method to rename with out disturbing all of those?

A quick google search lead me to

```
ALTER TABLE OLD_NAME RENAME TO NEW_NAME
```

Please let me know if this is the right approach

Thanks&Regards

Comment: Take a look here (preserves grants,etc): [rename](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9019.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rename a table, the grants, partitions, indexes, triggers and constraints are not affected.

However, references to the table are not automatically updated - so you'll need to fix any synonyms, as well as any code (e.g. in views, stored procedures, packages, and triggers on other tables) that refers to the table directly.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#sthref5046

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a right approach to rename a table in oracle, or you can either use,

```
RENAME old_name TO new_name;
```

But it invalidates all objects that depends on this table.